# on_change in override view field in openerp not working

Tags: openerp-7

the parent of action_type field

```
<group>
   <field name="action_type"/>
</group>
```

this is my code on_change not working while it works without overriding

```
<record id="hr_custom_action_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">hr.infraction.action.wizard.form</field>
        <field name="model">hr.infraction.action.wizard</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr_infraction.hr_infraction_action_wizard_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="/form/group/group/field[@name='action_type']">
                <field name="action_type" on_change="take_action(context)"/>
        </xpath>
        <xpath expr="/form/group[2]" position="after">
                <group string="Discount Days" attrs="{'invisible': [('action_type','!=','discount_days')]}">
                    <group>
                        <field name="penalty_days_value"/>
                    </group>
                    <group></group>
                </group>
        </xpath>
        </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one,

```
<field name="action_type" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="on_change">take_action(context)</attribute>
</field>
```